# Why is this attempt at getting length property on array failing in AS3?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3

I'm getting data from an SQL database.

```
var result: SQLResult = sqlStatement.getResult();
var resultsArray:Array;

if (result != null)
{
    resultsArray = result.data;
    trace(resultsArray.length);
}
```

When there's data in the database, the above code works fine. When there's not data, it errors out on the trace line...

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

Why is that? Why is it making it through the conditional when result is null?

Thank you.

Comment: `result.data` is null, you're checking only `result`

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't look like SQL. Would you kindly add a tag for what that is?

Comment: The **result** might be not **null**, but the **result.data** could still be (quote from https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/SQLResult.html#data): *If a statement does not return any data this property is null. This is the case if the statement is not a SELECT statement, or if it is a SELECT statement that returns 0 rows.* Thus, you are probably attempting to get the **length** property from the **null** rather than from a valid **Array** hence the error.